# Stop Testing If First Condition is True

Tags: c, control-flow

I want to avoid doing any further testing if a condition is true. Can I do it with:

```
if (n < 0)
{
    // code
}

for (n >= 0)
{
    // code
}
```

Or will the above code execute the first if statement if n < 0, but then also go on to evaluate the for statement as well?

Do I have to do the following:

```
if (n < 0)
{
    // code
}    
else
{
    for (int i = 0; n <= MAX; ++i)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to how if-else actually works in C. I'd suggest get basic book in C & code such basic things yourself.

Like for this case, to find out how it works I'll do the following:

```
if(condition==TRUE)
{
   printf("Condition TRUE\n");
}
else
{
   printf("Condition not TRUE\n");
}
```

Check the output to see whether both printfs are printed or not or which one is actually printed.